# Need help to resolve IE 8 z-index tooltip

Tags: html, css, tooltip

My code works with FF, Chrome but no in IE. The problem is that the bottom links are being shown over multiple lines inside the tool-tip.

This is all my code (no additional CSS) css:

**CSS FILE**

```
.hint,[data-hint] {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;}
.hint:before,.hint:after,[data-hint]:before,[data-hint]:after {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100000;
    pointer-events: none;}
.hint:hover:before,.hint:hover:after,.hint:focus:before,.hint:focus:after,[data-hint]:hover:before,[data-hint]:hover:after,[data-hint]:focus:before,[data-hint]:focus:after {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;}
.hint:before,[data-hint]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    z-index: 100001;}
.hint:after, [data-hint]:after {
    content: attr(data-hint);
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    line-height:1.3em;
    text-align:center;
}
.hint--bottom:before {
  margin-top: -12px; }
.hint--bottom:after {
  margin-left: -18px; }
.hint--bottom:before, .hint--bottom:after {
  top:  100%;
  left: 15px;}
.hint--info:after {
color:#5B5957!important;
border:1px solid #335088;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(97,97,97,0.7);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(97,97,97,0.7);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(97,97,97,0.7);   
  }
.hint--info.hint--top:before {
  border-top-color: #335088; }
.hint--info.hint--bottom:before {
  border-bottom-color: #335088; }
.hint--info.hint--left:before {
  border-left-color: #335088; }
.hint--info.hint--right:before {
  border-right-color: #335088; }
```

**and my HTML is:**

```
<ul> 
<li>Features</li>
<li><a href="#" class="hint--bottom  hint--info" data-hint="test test  test test  test test  test test test test">Updates</a></li>
<li>Features</li>
<li><a href="#" class="hint--bottom  hint--info"  data-hint="awdawd">Examples</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="hint--bottom  hint--info" data-hint="awdawd">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

see market as red image
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9686181/5025627/7e889594-6b23-11e4-9c95-89016aa0b29f.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue that you are having is that there are known issues with z-index on IE8 (Launched in 2009).

The bug report is [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

So firstly I would advice you to upgrade your browser as this IE 8 has a low market-share of browsers [statistics for IE8](http://www.theie8countdown.com/).

**The workaround**

From the information I have found, if you simple change the z-index values from 10000 -> 10001. To going between 10001 -> 10002 that will solve your problem.

*Thankfully I do not have IE 8, and my Browserstack account is playing up so unfortunately I can not verify the fix. But this should give you enough information*

Comment: This not solve my problem link is showed over my tooltip https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9686181/5025627/7e889594-6b23-11e4-9c95-89016aa0b29f.png see market as red image

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have over 16000 visits with IE8 and is around 13% of website visits. i try to change z-index as follow, but with no success :(